# How can I create tables from this ER diagra?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to map this ER diagram (IMAGE BELOW) into a relational database. I'm not sure my SQL is correct. Specifically, I don't quite understand if my primary and foreign keys are correct. I would greatly appreciate some help.

[image: ER Diagram]

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    A1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
    A2 INT
);


CREATE TABLE B (
    B1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
    B2 INT
);

CREATE TABLE R (
    R1 INT,
    A1 INT,
    B1 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(A1),
    FOREIGN KEY(A1) REFERENCES A(A1),
    FOREIGN KEY(B1) REFERENCES B(B1)
);
```

Comment: You dont need R1 in your Relationship table. A1 as PK is enough

Comment: But how could I do it with R1 if I wanted to? Also, how do I know what is supposed to be the primary key of R since both A and B have a one to one relationship?

Comment: If A and B has one to one relationship. Then you can remove R1, and define Primary Key on either `A1` or `B1` and define Unique on `B1` or `A1` (vice versa)

Comment: But R has an attribute. I don't think I can delete it

Comment: This part is not clear in your problem statement. If you want to keep it, you can keep it then.

Comment: There is an image